# Integral domains examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification, integral-domain

I am supposed to give an example of
1) an infinite integral domain of characteristic $5$, and
2) an integral domain which is not a field.

Respectively, examples I chose were $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Are these correct or do you have different/better examples?

Comment: 1.) No, $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is not infinite. Or do you mean the ring of $5$-adic integers ? 2.) yes.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @user3491648 I should say $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Is that correct then?

Comment: No, it's not correct then.

Comment: I think a simpler, and thus better, example for 2) is just $\mathbb Z.$ $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ is waaay to complicated.

Comment: @glitch in this site, yes. otherwise, people might think you mean the 5-adic numbers

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the prototypical integral domain. It's even in the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[X]$
2. $\mathbb Z$

Comment: I guess we can also have $ (\Bbb{Z}_{5})^{\Bbb{N}} $ for the first one?

Comment: @BerrickFillmore Is that one an integral domain?

Comment: You’re right! It isn’t! Hence, I think your example is the optimal one.

Comment: I suppose the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_5$ is more complicated.